# Не работает нажатие горячих клавиш через python keyboard в regedit. Как сделать, чтобы работало?

Tags: python, windows-10, pyautogui, python-keyboard, regedit

После переименования папки пользователя в Windows10 потребовалось сменить имя во всех путях реестра.

Решил создать скрипт на python.

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard as k
import os
import pyautogui as pg

os.startfile('C:/Windows/regedit.exe')
sleep(1)
k.send("f3")
sleep(1)
...
```

В других программах типа блокнота всё работает. А в regedit.exe k.send("f3") и через pyautogui пробовал, но команды не срабатывают, также вставка копирование в дальнейшем тоже не работает.
Если это защита реестра от срабатывания в нём посторонних программ, то как её обойти?

Comment: Фокус при запуске regedit на самой regedit, точно?

Comment: ну окно открывается поверх всего остального, с блокнотом аналогично работает всё ок, а как фокус сделать?